# How to use Tailwind imports with React Native- can tailwind be shortened to tw?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css

I am following this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJaFIGjyRms and at the 20 minute mark he imports Tailwind as `tw` then proceeds to use it in `app.js` I have done the exact same thing yet I am getting the error

> "TypeError: (0, _tailwindRn.tw) is not a function. (In '(0, _tailwindRn.tw)("justify-center items-center")', '(0, _tailwindRn.tw)' is undefined)"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WiRt.jpg)

my code:

```
        import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
        import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
        import {tw} from 'tailwind-rn';

        export default function App() {
          return (
            <View style={tw("justify-center items-center")}>
              <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your             app!</Text>
              <StatusBar style="auto" />
            </View>
          );
        }

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was facing the same problem
I used `npx setup-tailwind-rn` to set up tailwind. The below code worked for me:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
//import tw from 'tailwind-rn'
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn'


export default function App() {
  const tailwind = useTailwind();

  return (
    <View style={tailwind('flex-1 justify-center items-center')}>
      <Text>Hello World!!</Text>
      <Button title='Click-me'></Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `tailwind-rn` npm package.

More info https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-rn

Comment: I just did this using npm install tailwind-rn and I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you go back and look at the tutorial, they are using

`import tw from 'tailwind-rn';`

not

`import {tw} from 'tailwind-rn';`

You can name the default export of a library whatever you like in the import statement.

`import TailWind from 'tailwind-rn';`
`import t from 'tailwind-rn';`
etc.

Comment: I have changed it so it is the same as the tutorial, now I am getting a similar error: "TypeError: (0, _tailwindRn.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _tailwindRn.default)("flex-1 justify-center items-center")', '(0, _tailwindRn.default)' is undefined)"

Comment: Have you restarted Metro and rebuilt the project since installing the library?

Comment: Yes I have restarted metro and restarted the project in vs code and still getting the same error.

Comment: I rebuilt the project and am getting the same error, I have used ‘npm install tailwind-rn’ whereas in the tutorial he used ‘yarn add tailwind-rn’ the only reason I did not do this is because I don’t have a yarn lock on my project

Comment: Hey, I got stuck at the same error, did you manage to make it work?